# Spring model attribute/jsp not visible

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

Learning spring + jsp.

I am setting a model attribute in a method in a controller

```
@RequestMapping("/viewExpenses")
public String viewAllExpenses(Model model){

    List<Expense> expenses;
    expenses = expenseService.getAllExpenses();
    model.addAttribute(expenses);
    for(Expense e : expenses)
    System.out.println(e);
    return "viewExpenses";
}
```

where expenses size is > 1

```
Following is my jsp page:
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
    Hello ${user.firstName} <br> <a href="homepage">HOME</a>
</h2>
<div>All Expenses</div>
<span style=""></span>
<c:forEach var="expense" items="${expenses}">
    <c:out value="${expense.expenseId}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${expense.expenseName}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${expense.expenseType}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${expense.expensePrice}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${expense.purchaseDate}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${expense.expenseComments}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my output from the jsp(no errors):
Hello Pravat
HOME 
All Expenses

I wonder why the expenses are not populated in my jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your attribute an attribute name:

```
model.addAttribute("expenses", expenses);
```

*Background:* 
When a name is not supplied, Spring uses a generated name which is not the same as the variable name. The [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Conventions.html#getVariableName%28java.lang.Object%29) explain this:

> Determine the conventional variable name for the supplied Object based on its concrete type. The convention used is to return the uncapitalized short name of **the Class**, according to JavaBeans property naming rules: So, com.myapp.Product becomes product; com.myapp.MyProduct becomes myProduct; com.myapp.UKProduct becomes UKProduct.

Comment: do I have to give my attribute a name always. i think spring automatically names it, in my case it may be named as expensesList as its a lisk, Am i right??

Comment: I remembered something i read in the past about attribute names not able to recall now. As you suggested the code is now workinh

Comment: What about list? eg. List<Expense> expenses

Comment: i was asking about the name of the attribute(type=List<someClass>) which would be available in the jsp. I got the answer from the doc shared by you above. It will be the plural form of the collection type. eg expenses for List<Expense>. So my previous code without using a named attribute should be working, plz correct me if i am wrong

Comment: TBH, I never use Spring's generated name. Would say to set the name yourself, that way you know for definite what the name is

Comment: Also due to type erasure the name will _probably_ be `list`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give it a name

   ```
   model.addAttribute("expenses", expenses);
   ```
2. Return ModelAndView.
3. Always enclose body of if/for/etc into { } even it's single-lined.

Comment: thanks @Vitaly, points 2 and 3 are not relevant, though best practices